# REST API standard conventions for accessing resources

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I am exposing a REST API for customers to create and manager orders in the below format
`/api/v1/customers/{id}/orders [GET,POST] /api/v1/customers/{id}/orders/{id} [PUT, DELETE,GET]`

Now, I have another set of entities by `employees`. Employees should also be able to access the `[GET]` API for checking orders. What should be the naming conventions for accessing the orders for customers?

Should the following convention recommended

`/api/v1/employees?customer_id=34`
`/api/v1/employees/customers/orders`
`/api/v1/employees/customers/orders/{orderid}`

Comment: Those look ok apart from one thing. Since I do not know your requirements, it is still looks odd to me that you have customers inside employees like **/employees/customers/**. Should not you separate them ?

Comment: Yes. I had three options. I also believe that the  customers cannot be nested inside the employees

Comment: So, separate their endpoints like /api/v1/employees and /api/v1/customers then you are good to go.

Comment: how would the orders (GET, POST,DELETE) fit into to `api/v1/customers` and `/api/v1/employees` endpoints. What should be the REST convention

Answer (score 0):

Just use `/api/v1/orders`, `/api/v1/orders?customer={customerId}` and `/api/v1/orders/{orderId}` and check the authorization of the user for certain operations. As of the operation descriptions you need to respond with a hypermedia containinig the possible operations for the actual authorization and resource(s) as hyperlinks.

Comment: I want to have two separate endpoints. One endpoint for the employees and another for customers. 
`api/v1/orders` - for Customers
`api/v1/employees` - for employees

Comment: @zilcuanu Why? .

Comment: Because, I want to apply security configuration rules based on the entry point for both customers and employees.

Comment: @zilcuanu Is it necessary to do it based on entry point? The respresentation can depend on the security rules. It contains only the hyperlinks allowed for the actual user. You can decide what to send based on the hyperlink type and its documentation. The client should check only the link relation. https://restfulapi.net/hateoas/

Comment: I guess, we should have multiple entry points to access the resource. Lets consider a use case where we authenticate a user with form based credentials and employees using OAuth2.0. The datasource for authentication will be different. In this usecase, how can we implement using the approach you are suggesting. To display the hyperlinks, first we would have to authenticate and authorize right? Is my reasoning justified?

Comment: @zilcuanu I am not sure I understand your context. Where does the REST client run, is it in the browser?